# google analytics user engagement frequency

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

New to Google Analytics and couldn't figure out how to get this to show.

I would like to figure out how frequently a user visits our site after they've registered.  The reason is I want track their engagement following their registration.

So let's say user registered at week 0, I want to figure out how many times they come back in week 1, week 2 and week 3.  This way I can tell whether users tend to stay engaged for first 2 weeks, then slowly loses interests, or their interests grows as the weeks goes by after they've registered.  Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set a custom variable at visitor level when your users register. Use that to build a segment for visitors that have at some point registered at your site. Apply that segment to the "frequency and recency" report (audience->behaviour->frequency and recency).

The custom variable will allow you to recognize visitors that have registered (even if  they are not currently logged in) until they change browsers or delete their GA cookies.

Comment: Thanks.  I did use a custom variable for these visitor when they register.  However, with that, I'm only able to get the days since last visit.  I'm unable to get the number of visits during their 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so forth weeks after their registration.  I imagine I need to define another custom variable to identify when a user is in their 1st, 2nd, 3rd week then based on that, generate a report to see how many visits are in their 1st week after registration, how many in their 2nd week, etc.  Any idea?